# Why should I use `sudo` with the `passwd` command to change the password of another user?

Tags: permissions, filesystems, sudo, passwd

If you look at the permission set of the `passwd` command, you will see this:

```
user@apple:~$ ls -l /bin/passwd
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 59976 Nov 24  2022 /bin/passwd
```

`/bin/passwd` has the SUID bit set and its owner is the `root` user. This means running the command `passwd` will run the command with the permissions of the `root` user.

Given that `passwd` already has `root` user privileges, why does it say this when I try to change the password of another user, `test`:

```
user@apple:~$ passwd test
passwd: You may not view or modify password information for test.
```

Running the same command, but with `sudo`, lets me change the password though. Why is that?

Comment: A SUID program **could** change another users password. The standard passwd program adds additional checks so it doesn't change another user's password unless it is being invoked by someone who is already running with root privileges.

Comment: Perhaps the key information you're missing is that every process has both a **real** uid and an **effective** uid, which are not the same when running a setuid program.  (We also have both real and effective group ids, too).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In this particular implementation the `passwd` command needs to run as the `root` user to be able to change anyone's password.

The `passwd` application has a piece of code that checks whether you are the `root` user or not, and if not then it refuses to let you change anyone else's password. If you are `root`, then you can change anyone's password.

For example, if you are logged in as `alice`, and run `passwd bob` then although the code will run as `root` it will refuse to let you change `bob`'s password. However, if `alice` runs `sudo passwd bob` then *because the `sudo` command runs its arguments as `root`* rather than as `alice`, the `passwd` application will let you change anyone's password.

Lines from `src/passwd.c`, obtained (on Debian) with `apt source passwd`:

```c
static bool amroot;             /* The caller's real UID was 0 */
…

/*
 * The program behaves differently when executed by root than when
 * executed by a normal user.
 */
amroot = (getuid () == 0);
…

/*
 * If the UID of the user does not match the current real UID,
 * check if I'm root.
 */
if (!amroot && (pw->pw_uid != getuid ())) {
    (void) fprintf (stderr, _("%s: You may not view or modify password information for %s.\n"), Prog, name);
    SYSLOG ((LOG_WARN, "%s: can't view or modify password information for %s", Prog, name));
    closelog ();
    exit (E_NOPERM);
}
```

Comment: As @ChrisDavies has pointed out, the reason `passwd` is `setuid` is not to give it full root privileges - it is required because otherwise a user wouldn't be able to change their own password - the reason being that `/etc/shadow` is only accessible by `root`.

Comment: @tink only in this implementation. I've come across other implementations of `passwd` where it's not setuid root but rather only setgid shadow

Comment: Chris - interesting: in those implementations - who'd be a member of shadow?

Comment: @tink nobody — the `/etc/shadow` file would be writable by group `shadow`.

Comment: @tink, isn't that the same thing? If `/etc/shadow` is only writable by the user "root", then a program needs to act as "root" to write it. Unless they also use capabilities to remove the special root privileges, it'll have the full superuser privileges.

Comment: Usually `/etc/shadow` is only writable by `root`, but *readable* by group `shadow`. That allows programs that are `setgid shadow` to **check** passwords, but root privileges will be required to **change** them.

Comment: @telcoM In the other implementation it may be read-write to the group `shadow`. So making `passwd` set-gid to shadow will allow it to update the password.

Comment: @Barmar Maybe. But I've understood the main point of `/etc/shadow` is that unlike classic `/etc/passwd` it is not readable by everyone, so not everyone can grab the password hashes for cracking them. But if only root can read `/etc/shadow`, then only root can check passwords, which means every password check will have potential for root compromise if there is a bug in the code (as every such program must be setuid root). So it makes sense to use the `shadow` group to allow selected programs to perform password checking, while keeping the power to change passwords more strictly regulated.

Comment: Ultimately, regardless of the privilege required to write to `/etc/shadow`, if you can do that you can write root's password and you have full access

Comment: @telcoM Only selected programs can perform password checking AND password changing. There's not much gained by restricting one of them to root user and the other to shadow group, you can use the group for both.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, you can do that, but it is not optimal. It violates the principle of minimum privilege: not every password-checking program needs to be able to change passwords too. If you make the privilege required for both operations the same, you needlessly expand the group of programs that **absolutely must** be free of vulnerabilities that would allow unauthorized code execution to avoid immediate root compromise ("game over"). So the ability to grant just read-only access to `/etc/shadow` when that's all that is needed does have value.

Comment: @telcoM Good point. The set of programs that need to check passwords is quite different from those that need to change them.

Answer (score 7):

Being able to change another user's password is a *massive* security breach, hence why `passwd` does not allow it unless you are already root.

Comment: That doesnt help much. Im already running `passwd` command with the permissions of the `root` user. Then why can't can I change the password of that user? Is there something else in play here?

Comment: That would have made for a worthwhile comment, but doesn't address the actual question; you're just stating the reason for why it shouldn't work, not why it doesn't work.

Comment: @tink: "you're just stating the reason for why it shouldn't work, not why it doesn't work" – That's not what the question asks. The question asks: "Why should I use `sudo` with `passwd` command to change the password of another user?" (Because otherwise any user could impersonate any other user) and "why does it say this when I try to change the password of another user" (Same reason) and "Running the same command, but with sudo lets me change the password tho. Why is that?" (root is all-powerful, so there would be no point in forbidding it).

Comment: @grassy It is slightly misleading to say that you are running passwd "with the permissions of the root user". The SUID bit means that passwd has access to the permissions of the root user. But passwd also knows who is _actually_ running it. It has the ability to use root permissions, but when it is run by a non-root user it will refuse, by design, because non-root users should not be able to change each other's passwords. The reason passwd has the SUID bit set is NOT to enable any user to change any password; it is for an unrelated technical reason (as described by other users.)

Comment: @tink, it is stated there, it doesn't work since _"passwd does not allow it unless you are already root"_.

Comment: @grassy, if you were trying to ask _"how does `passwd` know to refuse me unless I use `sudo`"_, then you should probably have asked that.